# Android-Studio I get no display in video thumbnail getView method

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to display the video in thumbnails style but i get no display, if anyone know what i'am done wrong please give me an idea to follow.

I get the idea in this tutorial

> http:android-er.blogspot.com/2011/05/display-video-thumbnail-in-listview.html

```
public class RemarksAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RemarksInformation> {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<RemarksInformation> remarksInformationList;

    public RemarksAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<RemarksInformation> remarksInformationList) {
        super(context, resourceId, remarksInformationList);
        this.context = context;
        this.remarksInformationList = remarksInformationList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    static class RemarksHolder{
        TextView remarks;
        TextView image_name;
        TextView image_path;
        TextView video_name;
        TextView video_path;
        TextView date_send;
        TextView time_send;
        TextView remarks_by;
        RelativeLayout image_wrapper;
        RelativeLayout video_wrapper;
        ImageView thumbnail;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        RemarksHolder holder = null;
        View v = convertView;
        if(v == null){
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view_remarks, null);
            holder = new RemarksHolder();
            holder.remarks = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt_remarks);
            holder.date_send = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt_date_send);
            holder.time_send = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt_time_send);
            holder.image_name = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.image_name);
            holder.image_path = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.image_path);
            holder.video_name = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.video_name);
            holder.video_path = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.video_path);
            holder.remarks_by = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.remarks_by);
            holder.image_wrapper = (RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.image_wrapper);
            holder.video_wrapper = (RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.video_wrapper);

            holder.thumbnail = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.vid);

            v.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (RemarksHolder)v.getTag();
        }
            holder.remarks.setText(remarksInformationList.get(position).getRemarks());
            holder.image_name.setText(remarksInformationList.get(position).getImage_name());
            holder.image_path.setText(remarksInformationList.get(position).getImage_path());
            holder.video_name.setText(remarksInformationList.get(position).getVideo_name());
            holder.video_path.setText(remarksInformationList.get(position).getVideo_path());

            Bitmap bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(remarksInformationList
                    .get(position).getVideo_path(), Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);

            holder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail); //Get no display 

            holder.date_send.setText(remarksInformationList.get(position).getDate_send());
            holder.time_send.setText(remarksInformationList.get(position).getTime_send());
            holder.remarks_by.setText(remarksInformationList.get(position).getRemarks_by());

            holder.image_wrapper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ((ListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0);
                }
            });
            holder.video_wrapper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ((ListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0);
                }
            });

        return v;
    }
```

Comment: maybe check if the path of the video is correct?

Comment: The path is correct but the bmThumbnail is null how to fix this?

Comment: For some video ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(remarksInformationList
                    .get(position).getVideo_path(), Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND); may return null, check that too.

Comment: Yes ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(remarksInformationList .get(position).getVideo_path(), Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND); is returning null you have an idea how to fix this and why is returning null?

Comment: I forgot, the path is from Mysql database and i store the video to folder

Comment: The path is ok, i can download the video from the browser, but the bmThumbnail is null

Comment: `May return null if the video is corrupt or the format is not supported`. What is the extension of the videos?

Comment: The extension is 3gp and i can play the video on my machine

Comment: The only thing I can suggest right now is to create a separated method and manually input the video path into `createVideoThumbnail` and see if it works. You can try other file extension, too.

Comment: Mind sharing the paths?

Comment: I cannot share the path because is only a port forward Ip address is not a domain yet

Comment: Not able to chat  i have only 17 rep.